# Why do I keep getting errors for stray tags in my HTML?

Tags: html

I am using the W3C validation service report on my code, and I keep getting an error saying "Stray end tag "head", but I can't see what the problem is? My head contains a title and an opening and closing tag? is there perhaps a self-closing child element that influences the parent container? Or something else that I am missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head class="page-head">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="Tobias' Portfolio" content="This is the portfolio website that Tobias Rasmussen has developed during his first weeks as CareerFoundry.">
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css"> <!-- This link goes to a CDN (Content dilivery network), downloading a file that resets/normalizes the client's CSS. THIS MUST COME BEFORE THE LINK TO OUR STYLESHEET! -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- This tag embeds the roboto condensed font from Google Fonts onto my HTML file. Note: it is important to put BEFORE the link to the styles.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.production.css"> <!-- The link to the external stylesheet-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!--viewport tag-->
  <div>
    <header class="page-header">
      <img src="img/my_logo.png" alt="Logo with the name Tobias Rasmussen in a black font on a white background" class="page-header__item page-header__logo">
      <nav class="main-navigation page-header__item">
        <ul role="menubar" class="navigation-list">
          <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#home" role="menuitem" class="navigation-list__item navigation-list__item--active">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation">
            <a href="about.html" role="menuitem" class="navigation-list__item" target="_blank">About</a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation">
            <a href="contact.html" role="menuitem" class="navigation-list__item" target="_blank">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation" >
            <a href="work.html" role="menuitem" target="_blank" class="navigation-list__item">My Work</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your head tag should not end at the bottom, as it should not contain the **header** and other tags, that should be contained in the body.

The  element is a container for metadata (data about data) and is placed between the `<html>` tag and the `<body>` tag.

Metadata is data about the HTML document. Metadata is not displayed.

Metadata typically define the document title, character set, styles, scripts, and other meta information.

The following elements can go inside the  element:

```
<title> (required in every HTML document)
<style>
<base>
<link>
<meta>
<script>
<noscript>
```

You can read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_head.asp

A basic html example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```